# Kubernetes activeDeadlineSeconds not killing process

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using `activeDeadlineSeconds` in my `Job` definition but it doesn't appear to have any effect. I have a CronJob that kicks off a job every minute, and I'd like that job to automatically kill off all its pods before another one is created (so 50 seconds seems reasonable). I know there are other ways to do this but this is ideal for our circumstances.

I'm noticing that the pods aren't being killed off, however. Are there any limitations with `activeDeadlineSeconds`? I don't see anything in the documentation for K8s 1.7 - https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#jobspec-v1-batch I've also checked more recent versions.

Here is a condensed version of my CronJob definition -

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: kafka-consumer-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:  # JobSpec
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 50   # This needs to be shorter than the cron interval  ## TODO - NOT WORKING!
      parallelism: 1
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is actually a known bug in 1.7. It was fixed in version 1.8

https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/10755
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32149

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"`. This will terminate previous running pod then start a new one.

Check comments from here: [ConcurrencyPolicy](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/b7bd5f2d334ce968edc54f5fdb2ac67ce39c56d5/batch/v1beta1/types.go#L108)

Comment: Often a good choice. However, In my particular scenario, I wanted to give my pods time to gracefully exit before any new ones came up. Say new pods come up every 1 minute, I wanted to send them the SIGTERM signal at 50 seconds (via `activeDeadlineSeconds` then SIGKILL at 55 seconds. Helpful for connection cleanup